# How do I correctly use an array element in a sql statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a for loop in PHP in which each time it runs, it executes a modified SQL statement and returns the result. The modification is comparing a field in my database to an element in an array, but I get the error message

> Warning: Array to string conversion in ...

I only want to return the first row from the query so I am not using a while loop.

**Array declaration:**

```
$sql = "SELECT usersID FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Bad Query: $sql");
$ids = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $ids[] = $row;
    }
}
```

**For Loop:**

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM messages 
            WHERE (messagesFrom LIKE 'echo $messagesFrom' AND messagesTo LIKE '$ids[$i]') 
            OR (messagesFrom LIKE '$ids[$i]' AND messagesTo LIKE '%$messagesFrom%') 
            ORDER BY messagesID DESC";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die("Bad Query: $sql2");
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    print($row2);
 
}
```

I have tried a foreach loop but there is no change in my error message. I don't believe using implode() would work because I do not want to join the entire array together, I want to compare each individual element in the array.

Comment: RULE1: Never summarise an error message, its ALL USEFUL, so show us ALL of it

Comment: Why are you putting `echo` in the string? That will look for the literal text `echo` in `messagesFrom`.

Comment: `$ids[$i]` is still an array, so you need to get the value that you're looking for out of it

Comment: Or you might change this line `$ids[] = $row;` to `$ids[] = $row['usersID'];`

Comment: You should really use Prepared Statements for your queries. Prepare the query before the loop, and execute within the loop using the different values. Where has `$messagesFrom` come from? You don't show that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Full error message: Warning: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chatBox.php on line 19

Comment: And then of course, you need to let us know which line is line 19 as you show us LESS THAN 19 lines of code

Comment: @RiggsFolly line 19 is the $sql2. I did what you recommended and changed $ids[] = $row; to $ids[] = $row['usersID'] and now the error message is "Warning: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chatBox.php on line 22". Line 22 is "print($row2)".

Answer (score 0):

`$ids[$i]` is an array containing the row of the table. Even when you're only selecting a single column, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns an array. So you should extract the column into your array with:

```
$ids[] = $row['usersID'];
```

Then you should use a prepared statement with parameters rather than substituting the variable directly into the SQL. It's also easier to use `foreach` rather than `for`.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE (messagesFrom LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND messagesTo = ?)
        OR(messagesFrom = ? AND messagesTo LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%'))")
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $id, $messagesFrom, $id, $messagesFrom);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row2 = $mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    var_dump($row2);
}
```

You can't `print` an array, use `var_dump()` to print `$row2`.